# How do I authenticate my browser extension using API calls in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, authentication, playwright, browser-extension

I am testing on Chromium, and I have written the code to add the extension to the browser as below.

```
import { test as base, BrowserContext, chromium, Page } from "@playwright/test";
import path from "path";

const test = base.extend<{
    context: BrowserContext;
    api: any;
}>({
    context: async ({ }, use) => {
        const pathToExtension = path.join("tests", "extension");
        const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext("", {
            headless: false,
            args: [
                `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
                `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
            ]
        });
        await use(context);
        await context.close();
    }
})
```

The extension is being loaded without any issue. When I launch the extension using the extension URL, it asks for authentication. Logging in from the UI is not possible because of captcha. So I need to authenticate using the access token from API calls.

How do I achieve this, so that when I launch my extension using the URL, it should be logged in.

I created a method and got the access token and tried to add it to the context variable as extraHTTPHeaders like so

```
const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext("", {
            headless: false,
            args: [
                `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
                `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
            ],
            extraHTTPHeaders: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${getToken()}`,
            },
        });
```

But this is not working.